# Drag to change route in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps

In the web version of Google Maps, we can use "drag and drop" to get a custom route:

[image: drag-and-drop route marker]

How can we do this on Google Maps for Android? I tried to drag, but it doesn't work. It provides several alternative routes, but none of them is what I want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't drag in-route points of a given Google Maps for Android route, you can instead drag departure and arrival spots 'A/B' spots. Drag in-route points is indeed a very interesting feature, but not available in Google Maps for Android yet.

**You can drag the markers by doing:**

<sup>(click images for larger variant when needed)</sup>

1. Open Google Maps and tap "Direction" icon:

   [image: Screenshot]
2. Select either "My location" or a point in the map:

   [image: Screenshot]
3. In the example, I selected a point in the map:

   [image: Screenshot]
4. Same step with destination:

   [image: Screenshot]
5. You touch wherever you want the point in the map:

   [image: Screenshot]
6. Tap the button to get the route:

   [image: Screenshot]
7. When you see the departure/arrival green markers in the screen, you can just tap and hold to drag them to other locations. The route will get auto-updated to new locations.

   [image: Screenshot]

Comment: Thanks, but how can I drag the departure/arrival spots? It doesn't work on my phone.

Comment: Answer updated with step-2-step instructions, btw, my phone is in spanish.

Comment: I think the new Maps version doesn't support this yet. I have the A, B buttons but can't hold and drag. Thanks for your answer anyway.

Comment: **Note**: As of current, Google Maps has been updated so many times, and this answer doesn't reflect the current interface/logic.

Comment: Looks like this still isn't possible :(

Comment: still impossible. worse, sending directions from web to android removes dragged waypoints.

Answer (score 9):

I figured out that the only way to get around not being able to drag and change your route on the Google Maps app for Android, is to add multiple destinations. This is how you do it (according to Google support, with my CORRECTIONS added in)! ;)

Add multiple destinations:
Open the Google Maps app maps.
Search for your destination or tap it on the map.
In the bottom right, tap the blue circle. It'll show a car, bus, bike, taxi, or person walking.
Start the navigation.
In the bottom right, tap the little icon with the three dots in a column, and "search along route". Then "search for more places."
The search bar will appear at the top, and you will have to type in the intersection where you want to stop or "detour" to. You can also add a specific place, like a restaurant, for example.
Touch the location on the map when it pops up, and then "add stop" at the bottom right.
Now it will alter your route to include that stop along the way! PRESTO! :)

Notes:

You can (EDIT: are SUPPOSED to be able to) add up to 9 stops (but I haven't figured this out yet because it won't let me add any more than ONE STOP)!
Directions to multiple destinations, or waypoints, aren’t available for public transit or rides.
To change the order of your stops, find the destination you want to move and then touch and hold Reorder  and then drag the destination.
You can search for places along your route.

I HOPE THIS HELPS! "HAPPY MAPPING!!" :D

Answer (score 1):

If you use browsers that support "request desktop site" (e.g. FireFox), open Google Maps and request it. All the normal PC controls including drag route will appear.

Comment: I need it in the Maps app, since I want to use the route for navigation.

Answer (score 1):

Update your Google Maps android app it has now got add stops option.  You can add as many stops as you want.  After that press direction button, then you also have alternate route options black-gray color roads where you can tap and select.  Made easy.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to make a route on your desktop and then share it to yourself via email, and then open the link when you were ready to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've never answered an online question before, but here goes nothing. Pretty much all you have to do is start from your location then press the three vertical dots next to where it says "Your location" and click "Add stops". After that, you will be able to add the stops where ever you need them. I believe you can add up to 9 stops (the most I've ever needed was 4, so don't quote me on that). This feature is one I find very helpful if you are kinda sure where you're going but not 100% sure, like myself when going to any place over 30 mins away. I really hope this helps!! :)

Answer (score 0):

U cant drag the travelling blue line into desired route if in Lite Mode. Switch to full google maps mode.

https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3031966?p=litemode&hl=en&visit_id=1-636428057481232693-2574483336&rd=1

Answer (score 0):

Recently have the situation, when Google Maps route wasn't optimal, but I want to change it and save on the phone. Actually the only way I could do that via Google apps was only via My Maps https://www.lifewire.com/make-custom-route-on-google-maps-4126536 then open Android app My Maps, and my custom map. Not a quite easy way :)

Comment: That's an interesting idea, but it seems like more work than just adding extra stops in the Maps app directly.

Answer (score -2):

You can drag and change the route. Simply right click on the white circle and choose "Add Desitnation".
After this these white circles become movable.
Now getting used to these changes takes time but one tip is if you want to choose a straighter route than a route with twists and turns then simple drag a circle on the twisty route to the straight route but remember to drop it on straighter path rather than on junctions. In this way it will have no other way but to align it with the straight route alone.

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: The OP is asking how to do this on Android (which doesn't have a 'right-click'). They already know how to do it on a desktop computer.